# Implement a class to find invocation time of methods in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a following situation

```
public interface IPay
{
  void IncreasePay();
  void DecreasePay();
}

public class PayCalculation: IPay
{
  private int Pay;
  public PayCalculation( int Pay)
  {
    Pay = Pay;
  }
  public void IncreasePay()
  {
    Pay++;
  }
  public void DescreasePay()
  {
    Pay--;
  }
}
```

Now, I want to implement a class to print how long each Increase &DecreasePay method takes to invocation in milliseconds which should fit with existing clients of IPay.

I was trying to work myself with Stopwatch, but do not know how to implement it in a class without affecting existing clients...

Could some one please help me with the code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a wrapper class that also implements IPay and have it capture the amount of time it took.

```
public class PayWrapper : IPay
{
    private readonly IPay _wrapped;
    public PayWrapper(IPay wrapped)
    {
        if (wrapped == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(wrapped));
        _wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public void DecreasePay()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        _wrapped.DecreasePay();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

    }

    public void IncreasePay()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        _wrapped.IncreasePay();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Then when a class gets an IPay, it can use the wrapper like this:

```
public class ConsumerOfPay
{
    private IPay _pay;
    public ConsumerOfPay(IPay pay)
    {
        _pay = new PayWrapper(pay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi John, could you please help me understand the 2nd part. Which class is that? Ideally it should implement the IPay interface right in ConsumerOfPay?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aspect oriented approach, to implement your own attributes and add it to the method concerned.

```
[OnTransaction]
public void IncreasePay()
{
    Pay++;
}

[Serializable]
public class OnTransactionAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Log(DateTime.Now); // or other way such as StopWatch, whatever ...
    }
}
```

This way,  you will get notified every time IncreasePay() is called. Similarly, you can create another attribute for DescreasePay() and do some logic therein. Here [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_onmethodboundaryaspect) is an attribute defined in [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/), which is free for this attribute class. You can of course do it yourself.

**Note that you don't need to touch any internal logic of IncreasePay() or DescreasePay(), which is very useful and flexible.**

Comment: Sorry could you please explain these, I haven't come across aspect oriented stuff. Also, just saw using DateTime is not a efficient method but Stopwatch or performcounter

Comment: JUST an EXAMPLE, not the every bit of your solution is included!

Comment: Oh Thank you David, helps me to know more about the Aspect oriented thing. Will study further on these terms. :)

Comment: Links included! You will love it! Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much David :) Will surely study those links now :)